# if x and y => or if y => or if y in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is it possible?

eg:

```
z = something;
w = something else;

if (x == z && y == z){
   Do something;
} or if (y == w){
   Do something else;
or if...
or if...
```

basically what i want is a simpler way of writing:

```
if (x == z && y == z){
   Do something;
else if (x == z && y == w){
   Do something else;
if else...
if else...
```

that doesnt compares x and z everytime
(and that isnt the most obvious ones, like using mutiple ifs, unless that is the simpler one)

Comment: your question is very clear....

Comment: try it, that is the best way to find out - if you are lucky it might even compile.

Comment: if (x==z){ if (y ==z) {...} else if (y == w){...} }

Comment: If your y mechanic is the same every time, write a method to handle y.  if (x == z) { handleY(y); }

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you just want nested if/else.

```
if (x == z) {
    if (y == z) {
        ...
    } else if (y == w) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's precisely what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Check for `x!=z` first:

```
if (x != z)
{
  // maybe do nothing?
}
else if(y == z)
{
  // Do something;
}
else if (y == w)
{
}
```

or nested:

```
if (x == z)
{
  if(y == z){
    Do something;
  }
  else if (y == w){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (expression)
{
   case constant-expression:
      statement
      jump-statement
   [default:
      statement
      jump-statement]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the order of your comparisons:

```
if (y == z && x == z)
{
   Do something;
}
else if (y == w && x == z)
{
   Do something else;
}
else if ...
else if ...
```

x will only be compared to z when the first condition is true, thanks to shortcircuiting.

Comment: The point is that here, if `y == Z` and `y == W` are both false, then `x == z` will be compared twice.  That's what he's trying to avoid (and if `x` or `z` causes side effects, or is expensive to calculate, it could matter).

Comment: @Servy that's the point of short-circuit comparisons. In the case you describe, x and z are never compared. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.110).aspx  "if x is false, y is not evaluated"

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say where both `y == z` and `y == w` are true and `x == z` is false.  In that case you evaluate `x == z` twice.

Comment: @Servy but then z == w, which is unlikely.

Comment: Performing this refactor does make the redundant execution less likely, but still possible.  Now assume that each of the boolean expressions relied on completely unrelated variables (a common example) in which you have `if(A && B) else if (C && B)`.  You can simply refactor that to not compare both to `B` through nested `if` statements.  If nothing else, it results in less typing and makes the code easier to read.  Given that it also has equal or better performance implications I see no reason to prefer this method, even if it's only *slightly* incorrect instead of *completely* incorrect.

Comment: If you make the assumption that the expressions have completely unrelated variables, you lose the essence of the question.  In the case where z == w, it is redundant to check y == z and then y == w.  It is unlikely the programmer would write such conditions.

Comment: It doesn't lose the essence of the question, it just looses the essence of this answer.  All of the other answers apply to either case equally.

Comment: I mis-spoke and then corrected my mistake.  You on the other hand are using an unnecessarily complex solution to a very simple problem for which your answer is better than what's in the OP, but only mitigates, and doesn't eliminate, the problem he's trying to get rid of.  It also adds unneeded complexity, would become harder to maintain, and doesn't reduce the redundancies in the code itself.

Comment: it is my position that "add another layer of nesting" leads to less maintainable code.  One level may be fine, but there is a limit to how many levels may be added before other techniques must be researched.  I am not advocating this answer as a magic bullet to solve all comparison woes, but I am pointing out that "short circuiting operations can reduce comparisons performed" - which is true, and answers what is being asked - "doesnt compares x and z everytime".

Comment: If the issue is multiple levels of nesting you can address that issue by refactoring out sections into another method, or by computing intermediate boolean values, storing them as variables, and then using those to flatten the `if` statements.  Note that your method wouldn't scale particularly well with multiple conditions; it would just scale horizontally instead of vertically.  Short circuiting is a great tool, which can be very effective in certain situations, I just don't think that this is an appropriate application of it.

Comment: Scaling horizontally is better than scaling vertically. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Scale_horizontally_.28scale_out.29 Neither of which apply to this answer (or question).

Comment: Actually, that link *does* apply to this example, it simply has the dimensions reversed.  You're suggesting to have less `if` statements that are more complex (that link's definition of scaling vertically/up) as opposed to more `if` statements that are simpler (that link's definition of scaling horizontally/out).  It just so happens that scaling horizontally by that definition involves text in code that is longer vertically and shorter horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison once and save the result in a local boolean variable.  Then use that bool in the if statements.

```
bool b = (x==z);
if (b && y == z){
    Do something;
else if (b && y == w){
    Do something else;
```

I would still do the nested if that others have recommended, though.